# I am trying to validate the attached html using nothing but javascript so that at all inputs have at least something entered, checked or selected

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, validation, dom

I got my validation to work and looped through most of it to ensure it is selected. However, it skips the hobbies checkbox and doesn't check whether it is selected, while it checks everything else and sends an alert. The Instruction are listed below and my code is attached.

Using nothing but the DOM, validate the attached html using nothing but javascript so that at all inputs have at least something entered, checked or selected. That means no html5 form validation's "required" attribute. Try looping through all elements in the form and evaluating what type they are before you test whether there is a value or whether radio buttons or checkboxes have a checked property of "true"

Your user has nothing but Internet Explorer 8 which means you cannot use html5's required attribute!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Validate me</title>
<script>
    function validateMe(){
        for (let i=0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
            let msg = document.forms[0].elements[i].name;
            if(document.forms[0].elements[i].value == "") {
                alert("Please enter your " + msg);
                document.forms[0].elements[i].focus();
                return false;
            }
            var radioGrp = false;
            if(document.forms[0].elements[i].type == "radio"){
                let msg = document.forms[0].elements[i].name;
                const numelems = document.getElementsByName(msg).length;
                let elem = document.getElementsByName(msg)

                for(var j = 0; j < numelems; j++) {
                    if (elem[j].checked == true) {
                        radioGrp = true;

        }
    }
                if(radioGrp == false) {
                    alert("Please enter your " + msg);
                    return false;
                }
                var checkboxGrp = false;
            if(document.forms[0].elements[i].type == "checkbox"){
                let msg = document.forms[0].elements[i].name;
                const numelems = document.getElementsByName(msg).length;
                let elem = document.getElementsByClassName(msg)

                for (var j = 0; j < numelems; j++){
                    if (elem[j].checked == true){
                        checkboxGrp = true; 

                }
                    }
            if (checkboxGrp == false){
                alert("Please select your "+ msg);
                return false; 
            }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
At least one piece of data has to come in from every input type.
<form action="form.html" method="get" onsubmit="return validateMe();"><br>
Name:<input type="text" id="test" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter Full Name"><br>
Year in College:<br>
First Year<input type="radio" name="year" value="First Year">
Second Year<input type="radio" name="year" value="Second Year">
Third Year<input type="radio" name="year" value="Third Year"><br>

Hobbies<br>
Baseball <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="baseball">  
Football <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="football">  
Hockey <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="hockey"><br>
Favorite Show <select name="show">
<option value="">Choose Below</option>
<option value="ATHF">Aqua Teen Hunger Force</option>
<option value="Family Guy">Family Guy</option>
<option value="Simpsons">Simpsons</option>
</select><br>
Comments<br>
<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="comments"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="enter me">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The check to see if the element type is “checkbox” is inside the handler for when the element type is “radio”, so it will never be executed. Consider keeping your code propertly indented, and this kind of error will be easier to spot.

Comment: Which line of code are you referring to? My Chrome dev tools didn't spot any error. If you are under hobbies the element type is set to checkbox? Would you be able to tell me which line of code or pinpoint it to me?

Comment: It’s a logic error, not a syntax error.

if(document.forms[0].elements[i].type == "radio"){
…
    if(document.forms[0].elements[i].type == “checkbox”){
…
    }